# Teraterm linux equivalent to push binary file to device

Tags: flash-memory, teraterm

I am trying to modify the OpenNFM firmware for a pet project. The board I am using is Olimex LPC H3131. In windows, I compile the binary using IAR embedded workbench and use Teraterm(serial port) to send(send as binary) the binary to the board. This sets up the board to work as a USB device. How do I push the binary to the device in Linux?

I have used minicom. I get the 'LPC31xx READY FOR PLAIN IMAGE' message similar to Teraterm. Then I use 'CTRL+A' followed by 'S' to send file. I select 'ASCII' in the next screen and then enter the path to the binary. I get a successful transfer and a 'Download Complete' message in minicom. But nothing happens afterwards. I donot even get the output(log comments for debugging) that I get when using Teraterm, nor does the board show up as a USB storage device.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to send a binary file with minicom as ASCII you need to encode it first. The problem is you need to decode it again on the receiving side, so I guess you cannot follow this route.

Luckily, you can customize minicom to add a new transfer protocol. See here:
https://gist.github.com/cstrahan/5796653

As you can see the procedure is quite straight forward:

1) Save the script somewhere in your system, for instance `/usr/bin/bin-xfer.sh`

2) Give it the right permissions: `$sudo chmod +x bin-xfer.sh`

3) Run minicom's setup: `$sudo minicom -s` and select file transfer protocol on the menu

4) Add a new entry hitting <kbd>J</kbd>, give a name like `binary` and press enter to move to the next menu, then add the command line `/usr/bin/bin-xfer.sh -o %l` and set other options according to the link

5) Save you configuration and exit the setup menu

Then from minicom you can invoke the new menu you just added with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

**EDIT:** After testing this solution myself on Ubuntu 19.04 I realized the script was not working (because it uses a different function definition that's not supported). But it's very easy to fix, just change line 5 from `function exists {` to `exists() {` . It is also a good idea to install pv with `$sudo apt-get install pv` if you want to monitor the progress of the transmission.

As a side note, you don't need to use minicom, you can use this script as a standalone tool, but to do that you need to set up the port with stty, something like:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 raw cs8 -ixoff -cstopb -parenb
```

And then run the script with:

```
$ bin-xfer.sh -i bin_file_to_send -o /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I have also tested [this](https://github.com/devttys0/serio) python script and it also works and could be added to minicom's menu in a similar way.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response. I followed your instructions. Something still seems to be off. Can you please go through the screenshots and let me know what I did wrong? https://imgur.com/Vnmt2HI https://imgur.com/7AeRcgE https://imgur.com/NfXHmJX https://imgur.com/KrEJ6zm https://imgur.com/v7uQ71E

Comment: Hello Kevin, you're welcome. Bayour sed on your last screenshot you seem to have selected the `ascii` option from the menu (I read "ascii upload of...", can you try again? you should see "binary upload..."

Comment: That screenshot was to show that the file is being sent in ascii but not in binary. When I select binary, the request simply times out. https://imgur.com/eNKXYec This is what i get. as soon as i select binary and enter the path, I simply return to this command window,

Comment: I guess that means the script is not working. I did not have to check it myself, but I'll do it over the weekend and let you know what I find.

Comment: Hello Kevin, take a look at the update on my answer, I have tested it and now it works.

Comment: I totally forgot to `chmod +x bin-xfr.sh` and was tearing my hair out trying to send binary using minicom. Bless and thank you.